# how to get exact position of music playback in pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I know we can use `.get_raw()` on a Sound object to get a raw array of audio data, and I would like to get the exact values to pass as array indexes based on current playback position (for example `raw_array[pos:pos+offset]` would represent audio from current position plus an offset value, but Sound objects do not have a `.get_pos()` method (and it does not seem exact anyway), how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently no real API is exposed for such a thing. The closest thing for that I've found is [pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_pos). The downside is that you are only able to play only one audio at the time with `pygame.mixer.music`. It feels like a missing feature. Feel free to create a new [issue](https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/issues/new/choose) for that. (With `pygame.mixer.Sound.get_at()` it would make sense if `pygame.mixer.Sound.set_at()` would also exist).

After more in-depth search, I've found out that pygame for mixer internally uses `SDL_mixer`<sup>1</sup>, which also seems to not expose such an API<sup>2</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/blob/main/src_c/mixer.h</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl-mixer-how-to-get-music-position/12374</sup>

Comment: thanks for your answer, currently I managed to accomplish that by keeping track of time elapsed since music start and creating a new Sound object having the raw array sliced by that value as buffer argument.